# Como excluir caracteres não numéricos, que foram adicionados por mask?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Opa, tudo bem? Estou fazendo um projeto onde preciso mostrar o resultado de um cálculo na hora, no formulário mesmo,e posteriormente salvá-los no banco de dados.
 
O problema é que quando eu comecei a utilizar '**masks**' com **JQuery**, para facilitar a digitação do usuário, os cálculos passaram a incluir os símbolos de percentagem e monetários, por exemplo, e resultar valor **NaN**.
Alguém poderia me ajudar mostrando como eu posso tratar esses dados digitados, ignorando os símbolos e filtrando-os (**mas mantendo também casas decimais**), para que somente os números sejam calculados e que as 'masks' continuem apenas para facilitar o entendimento na hora de preencher o formulário? Agradeço desde já.

Aqui vão alguns detalhes:
**Formulário onde são digitados os valores a serem calculados:**
*Os dados são apresentados no span.*

```
<form>
    <label>Custo 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="custo1" onkeyup="calcular();">

    <label>IPI:</label>
    <input type="text" id="perc_ipi" onkeyup="calcular();">

    <label>ST:</label>
    <input type="text" id="perc_st" onkeyup="calcular();">

    <label>Outros:</label>
    <input type="text" id="perc_outros" onkeyup="calcular();">

    <label>Frete:</label>
    <input type="text" id="perc_frete" onkeyup="calcular();">

    <label>FCPST:</label>
    <input type="text" id="perc_fcpst" onkeyup="calcular();">

    <label>STUF:</label>
    <input type="text" id="perc_stuf" onkeyup="calcular();">

    <label>Desconto:</label>
    <input type="text" id="perc_desc" onkeyup="calcular();">

    <label>Custo 2:</label>


    <span type="text" id="custo2"></span>
</form>
```

**Função que faz os cálculos:**

```
function calcular() {           
        var custo1 = Number(document.getElementById('custo1').value);
        var calcIPI1 = Number(document.getElementById('perc_ipi').value);
        var calcST1 = Number(document.getElementById('perc_st').value);
        var calcOutros1 = Number(document.getElementById('perc_outros').value);
        var calcFrete1 = Number(document.getElementById('perc_frete').value);
        var calcFCPST1 = Number(document.getElementById('perc_fcpst').value);
        var calcSTUF1 = Number(document.getElementById('perc_stuf').value);
        var calcDesconto1 = Number(document.getElementById('perc_desc').value);
        var elemResult = document.getElementById("custo2");


        //Fórmulas das percentagens
        calcIPI2 = custo1 * calcIPI1 / 100 + custo1;
        calcST2 = custo1 * calcST1 / 100;
        calcOutros2 = custo1 * calcOutros1 / 100;
        calcFrete2 = custo1 * calcFrete1 / 100;
        calcFCPST2 = custo1 * calcFCPST1 / 100;
        calcSTUF2 = custo1 * calcSTUF1 / 100;

        //Gerando o custo 2.
        custo2 = calcIPI2 + calcST2 + calcOutros2 + calcFrete2 + calcFCPST2 + calcSTUF2;

        custo2 = custo2 - custo1 * calcDesconto1 / 100;

        elemResult.innerText = String(custo2);

}
```

**Acredito que seja desnecessário colocar as masks aqui, mas caso seja preciso:**

```
//JQuery Maskmoney
        $(function() {
          $('#custo1').maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$  ', reverse: 'false', decimal: ',', thousands: '.', precision: 2 });
        })

        $(function() {
          $('#venda').maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$  ', reverse: 'false', decimal: ',', thousands: '.', precision: 2 });
        })

        //JQuery Mask

        $('#perc_ipi').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_frete").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_outros").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_st").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_fcpst").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_stuf").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#perc_desc").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

        $("#custo2").mask("999.999.990,00", {reverse: true});

        $("#venda").mask("999.999.990,00", {reverse: true});
```

Comment: para pegar o valor sem a máscara, deve utilizar a função cleanVal(), conforme [referência do plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-the-unmasked-typed-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está resultando `NaN` porque você está usando `Number()` em campos onde a máscara está adicionando caracteres não numéricos, como `R$`, espaço e `%`.

Você pode criar uma função que remove o que não interessa para os cálculos (tudo o que não for número, exceto a vírgula das decimais, que será substituída por ponto).

```
function somenteNumero(n){
   n = n.replace(/[^\d,]/g,'') // retira tudo que não for número, exceto a vírgula
   .replace(",", '.'); // substitui a vírgula por ponto
   return +n; // retorna em formato de número
}
```

E ainda pode utilizar `.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});` no resultado para formatar o valor do resultado em Real.

Veja o resultado:

```js
function somenteNumero(n){
n = n.replace(/[^\d,]/g,'')
.replace(",", '.');
return +n;
}

function calcular() {           
     var custo1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('custo1').value);
     var calcIPI1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_ipi').value);
     var calcST1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_st').value);
     var calcOutros1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_outros').value);
     var calcFrete1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_frete').value);
     var calcFCPST1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_fcpst').value);
     var calcSTUF1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_stuf').value);
     var calcDesconto1 = somenteNumero(document.getElementById('perc_desc').value);
     var elemResult = document.getElementById("custo2");


     //Fórmulas das percentagens
     calcIPI2 = custo1 * calcIPI1 / 100 + custo1;
     calcST2 = custo1 * calcST1 / 100;
     calcOutros2 = custo1 * calcOutros1 / 100;
     calcFrete2 = custo1 * calcFrete1 / 100;
     calcFCPST2 = custo1 * calcFCPST1 / 100;
     calcSTUF2 = custo1 * calcSTUF1 / 100;

     //Gerando o custo 2.
     custo2 = calcIPI2 + calcST2 + calcOutros2 + calcFrete2 + calcFCPST2 + calcSTUF2;

     custo2 = custo2 - custo1 * calcDesconto1 / 100;

     elemResult.innerText = custo2.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});

}

//JQuery Maskmoney
     $(function() {
       $('#custo1').maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$  ', reverse: 'false', decimal: ',', thousands: '.', precision: 2 });
     })

     $(function() {
       $('#venda').maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$  ', reverse: 'false', decimal: ',', thousands: '.', precision: 2 });
     })

     //JQuery Mask

     $('#perc_ipi').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

     $("#perc_frete").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

     $("#perc_outros").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

     $("#perc_st").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

     $("#perc_fcpst").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

     $("#perc_stuf").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

     $("#perc_desc").mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});

     $("#custo2").mask("999.999.990,00", {reverse: true});

     $("#venda").mask("999.999.990,00", {reverse: true});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<form>
<label>Custo 1:</label>
<input type="text" id="custo1" onkeyup="calcular();">

<label>IPI:</label>
<input type="text" id="perc_ipi" onkeyup="calcular();">

<label>ST:</label>
<input type="text" id="perc_st" onkeyup="calcular();">

<label>Outros:</label>
<input type="text" id="perc_outros" onkeyup="calcular();">

<label>Frete:</label>
<input type="text" id="perc_frete" onkeyup="calcular();">

<label>FCPST:</label>
<input type="text" id="perc_fcpst" onkeyup="calcular();">

<label>STUF:</label>
<input type="text" id="perc_stuf" onkeyup="calcular();">

<label>Desconto:</label>
<input type="text" id="perc_desc" onkeyup="calcular();">

<label>Custo 2:</label>
</form>

<span type="text" id="custo2"></span>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!